# Does system restore restores security permissions?

Tags: windows, permissions, file-permissions, system-restore

I wanted to change the security permissions of some folder, but I targeted my root D drive instead.

I cancelled half way, but still; the majority of the files is affected and I want to revert my action.

Some people suggest that reverting back to a system restore point should fix the issue. Although this sounds great I am a bit sceptical and my nearest restore point is way back.

Can anyone confirm that security permissions are reset to the restore point's permissions?

Comment: you mean Windows System Restore?

Comment: @FranciscoTapia: yes, that's what I mean.

Comment: then the accepted answer is wrong, Windows System Restore only affect system files.

Comment: @FranciscoTapia: do you know where I can find some documentation on that?

Comment: there is it. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the image Shows:

> System Restore does not affect any of your documents, pictures, or
>   other personal data, and the process is reversible

[image]

That mean, if the files are not System Files or in some cases are not involved in some Windows Instalation, they will be kept intact.

You should determinate by yourself if the file is a System File or if is a Personal File Easy, for us it could be harder :)

---

Aditional Documentation [Here](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/what-is-system-restore)

Comment: And here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/313222 : `...this may not be helpful to restore security settings on application data and a Complete System backup may be needed for the same.`

Comment: @Stefan sometimes, is better to do a fresh install or load a complete backup, than spend a lot of our precious time in a task with success rate lower than 50% ><

Answer (score 1):

**Yes**, a System Restore should help you restore files security permissions.

However there are other methods [secedit](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/313222), [takeown](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753024.aspx), [cacls](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-in/library/bb490872.aspx) or [icacls](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753525.aspx) to do that

Comment: this is partially correct, System Restore affect system files, that mean only system files permissions will be fixed.